# Magento 2 - Not able to override CouponManagement Model

Tags: magento2, overrides, model, coupon

I am trying to override Magento\Quote\Model\CouponManagement core vendor file. What I am trying to achieve is change the default error message when the wrong coupon code is added.

My di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

 <preference for="\Magento\Quote\Model\CouponManagement" type="Ecs\VendorOverride\Model\CouponManagement" /> 

</config>
```

My CouponManagement.php

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Ecs\VendorOverride\Model;

use \Magento\Quote\Api\CouponManagementInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotDeleteException;
use \Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

/**
* Coupon management object.
*/
class CouponManagement extends \Magento\Quote\Model\CouponManagement
{
/**
 * Quote repository.
 *
 * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $quoteRepository;

/**
 * Constructs a coupon read service object.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository Quote repository.
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
) {

    $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;

}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function get($cartId)
{
    /** @var  \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
    $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);

    return $quote->getCouponCode();
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function set($cartId, $couponCode)
{ 
    /** @var  \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
    $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
    if (!$quote->getItemsCount()) {
        throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('Cart %1 doesn\'t contain products', $cartId));
    }
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);

    try {
        $quote->setCouponCode($couponCode);
        $this->quoteRepository->save($quote->collectTotals());
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(__('Could not apply coupon code'));
    }
    if ($quote->getCouponCode() != $couponCode) {
        throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('Coupon code is not valid or expired'));
    }
    return true;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function remove($cartId)
{
    /** @var  \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
    $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
    if (!$quote->getItemsCount()) {
        throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('Cart %1 doesn\'t contain products', $cartId));
    }
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
    try {
        $quote->setCouponCode('');
        $this->quoteRepository->save($quote->collectTotals());
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new CouldNotDeleteException(__('Could not delete coupon code'));
    }
    if ($quote->getCouponCode() != '') {
        throw new CouldNotDeleteException(__('Could not delete coupon code'));
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

I am able to print values inside get function but the set function is still returning value from vendor file.

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to change the copy, it's probably best to achieve this through the translation system rather than overriding a class. The `__()` function in your code snippet that the copy is a parameter of is Magento's translation method which allows you to change the text via string replacement before it's rendered to the page.

You'll need to create a translation file for your language and you can place this in your theme or module.

For more information, I'd recommend reading the Translations overview on Magento dev docs here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/translations/xlate.html

Otherwise, I'd suggest try clearing your cache and running di compilation (if you haven't already).

`bin/magento cache:flush`

`bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Comment: I tried using translation system and is able to do this.Thanks for pointing me out .